# Windows 7 Pro --> Windows 10 activated World Wide Web Publishing Service

Tags: windows, windows-10

After installing windows 10 upgrade the Windows 7 Pro --> Windows 10 activated World Wide Web Publishing Service on port 80. This was NOT running before the windows 10 upgrade and caused issues.

I was able to disable the service; but why did it get installed/activated?